# Create a list of unique values and the times repeated across

Tags: list, google-sheets, unique, countif

I'm obtaining a list of unique values with this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(A2:A1000,A2:A1000<>""),"\d+"))&"*",REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A1000,"\d+.+$"),1,FALSE))
```

I did this for 3 different sheets, in each sheet has different values but in some cases these are repeated across the sheets like this:

These are the final list after the formula:

[image]

After this I used this formula

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet3!$A$2:$A$500,A2)+COUNTIF(Sheet4!$A$2:$A$500,A2)+COUNTIF(Sheet5!$A$2:$A$500,A2)
```

I get this:

[image]

Actually it works as I want but is not a dynamic function I would like to have the list of the unique values and the times appearing across the sheets if is possible

Here is the problem with some text in the row that I have with []

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below `QUERY()` formula-

```
=QUERY({Sheet3!A:A;Sheet4!A:A;Sheet5!A:A},"select Col1, Count(Col1) 
where Col1 is not null 
group by Col1 
label Col1 'List of Values', Count(Col1) 'Count'")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey actually it works really good, but I'm still having the problem with some values that after the text have this ["randomtext"] but is the same text repited at the beggining, I updated the publication, there is a way to make a filter for this kind of values?